# How can I find out the linebreak penalty at a given point of text or a math formula?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

**How can I find out the linebreak penalty at a given point of text or a math formula?** An example would be the point before and after the equals sign here: `\(a + b = c\)`.

If I write complex formulas, I sometimes want to manually insert `\penalty` values, but the choice of number to get the effects I want (e.g., Do I really need `\penalty10000` to prevent a linebreak after some particular `\mathrel` in some particular formula?) often amounts to a long process of trial-and-error. Knowing what effective `\penalty` value there would be at a certain point within a formula without manual intervention will help reduce the space for experimentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeX automatically adds penalties after binary operations and relation symbols, but only at the outer level of a formula (for instance, not for formulas inside a `{...}` group or between `\left` and `\right`; also the arguments to `\mathbin` and similar commands make a subformula).

The value of these penalties is stored in the parameters `\binoppenalty` and `\relpenalty`. The default values are

```
\binoppenalty=700
\relpenalty=500
```

These automatic penalties are *not* inserted if an explicit penalty follows a binary operation or relation symbol. To wit,the following Plain TeX input

```
\showboxbreadth=1000 \showboxdepth=1000

$a+b=c$\showlists

$a+b=\penalty100 c$\showlists

\bye
```

produces, in the log file,

```
### horizontal mode entered at line 4
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
\mathon
\teni a
\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22217 plus 1.11108 minus 2.22217
\tenrm +
\penalty 700
\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22217 plus 1.11108 minus 2.22217
\teni b
\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
\tenrm =
\penalty 500
\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
\teni c
\mathoff
```

for the first line, while it gives

```
### horizontal mode entered at line 6
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
\mathon
\teni a
\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22217 plus 1.11108 minus 2.22217
\tenrm +
\penalty 700
\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22217 plus 1.11108 minus 2.22217
\teni b
\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
\tenrm =
\penalty 100
\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
\teni c
\mathoff
```

for the second line.

If you add `\penalty0` after `=` you simply make that a feasible break point; with the usual 500 a break is possible, with 10000 it is forbidden.

You *can't* know in advance what's a good value for getting a break. The only way to be sure to get a break after `=` is to add `\penalty-10000`. The line breaks are chosen by TeX by considering the paragraph as a whole.

Penalties that affect line breaking are only added in a few cases:

- math formulas, as seen above;
- after an explicit hyphen or ligature that ends with a hyphen, the parameter is `\exhyphenpenalty`;
- after a discretionary item (that might have been inserted by the hyphenation process), the parameter is `\hyphenpenalty`;
- at the end of the paragraph TeX adds

  ```
  \unskip\penalty10000\hskip\parfillskip\penalty-10000
  ```

  to finish it off.

The result of this is that there is no concept of “linebreak penalty at a point”. Penalties are just one of the factors TeX keeps into account for computing a series of line breaks, in order to get the fewer demerits.